# D3 time scale – ticks(count) yields error, omitting ticks(count) yields no error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm implementing a timeline feature and am using the [d3.time.scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales) object in D3 to make an axis. Here's the code:

```
var t = 1066555;

var xd = [new Date(t-10000), new Date(t)],
    x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(xd)
        .range([0, 300])
        .ticks(10);

var xaxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x);

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('height', 90).attr('width', 300);

svg.append('g').attr('class', 'x axis').call(xaxis);
```

Things work well until I add [`ticks()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#ticks) to scale initialization. When added, `.call(xaxis)` throws `Uncaught TypeError: scale.copy is not a function`. When `ticks()` is removed there is no error and the scale works as intended. According to the [ticks documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#ticks) specifying a count for ticks is legal. Any idea why this is throwing an error? The code is near identical to [Mike Bostock's time scale block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4403522).

I've made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/connorgr/4zgx9t59/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(xd)
        .range([0, 300]).ticks(10);
var xaxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
```

It should be added on the axis as below

```
x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain(xd)
        .range([0, 300])

var xaxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).ticks(10);
```

working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/4zgx9t59/2/)

Hope this helps!